# Is it possible to combine extension's Google Analytics stats with those of a site?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-analytics

I have a site which refers to the Chrome Web Store where users can download an extension advertised on the site. I do not want to lose track of those users decided to abandon downloading the extension. Currently I have the GA embedded in the site.
I was wondering if it's somehow possible (in order to determine our user acquisition price) to set up the same GA for the extension so that I could see those who clicked "Download" button on the site and ultimately came to use the extension.